# Could not find a declaration file for module error in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Typescript beginner here, trying to implement splitter to my project, i'm using SplitPane from "react-split-pane/lib/SplitPane"
and Pane from "react-split-pane/lib/Pane" in my typescript project but its giving me this error:

```html
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-split-pane/lib/Pane'. 'C:/.../node_modules/react-split-pane/lib/Pane.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-split-pane` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-split-pane/lib/Pane';`ts(7016)
```

it is working correctly without problem but still giving me that, it suggests to try
'@types/react-split-pane' but that is not working anymore 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-split-pane' 'This package has been deprecated'.

as i said in comments i imported it like this :

import SplitPane from "react-split-pane/lib/SplitPane";

import Pane from "react-split-pane/lib/Pane";

Any idea how to get rid of error ?

English is not my mother language so the could be mistakes.

my splitpane module:

[image]

Comment: Typescript can import it just fine https://tsplay.dev/mL45vm How are you importing and using this library?

Comment: @AlexWayne i tried this : 'import SplitPane, { Pane } from "react-split-pane";' and getting this : 'Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\node_modules\react-split-pane\dist\index.esm.js''

Comment: Are you sure it's installed? Did you run `npm install`? Maybe try removing your `node_modules` folder and reinstalling everything.

Comment: yes it is installed thats why it works... but in code under that import is red, i want to get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

> i'm importing it like this : import SplitPane from "react-split-pane/lib/SplitPane"; import Pane from "react-split-pane/lib/Pane";

You really should *never* go drilling into the directory structure of libraries for imports, unless the documentations *specifically* tells you to.

According to the [index file](https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane/blob/master/src/index.js) of that library, that's now how you are expected to import the values. The library exports like this:

```
export default SplitPane;
export { Pane };
```

And that means you should import those two values like this:

```
import SplitPane, { Pane } from 'react-split-pane'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BlMAG2BgAUUA7JAGjgG84X24AXzjZcBIuhgBaAM71GUsGyRlSaCKxnwYSLQEY4AXjgAeWg2bK4AegB8ajVrg6tAJiOn+SG7aA)

It also works in [a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-tdd-rmd3t?file=/src/App.tsx) with a full project:

---

Comment: others have imported it also same way as i did : https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane/issues/233

Comment: They probably are not using typescript. This package contains type information, but that's only valid for when you import from the root package name. Since this project is not written in typescript, then Typescript doesn't know the types of the individual files inside the library.

Comment: is there anyway to fix it or bypass ?

Comment: It works in that code sandbox link I posted. So you may need to figure out why your project is different from that sandbox. I can't really do that for you.

Comment: here someother has exact same problem and he fixed by ignoring: https://giters.com/tomkp/react-split-pane/issues/541

Comment: That solution will not import the types. But, honestly, [that issue](https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane/issues/541) has been open for two years. This library seems like a mess, at least with its typescript support. It looks like the project has been abandoned. I would look for another solution entirely, if I were you.

Comment: i dont need types for it i need that just to work, which it does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241705/discussion-between-walee-and-alex-wayne).